# I have some HTML stored in a field, how do I get the innerHTML on the server side of an element containing specific text?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, dom

I'm using ruby 1.8.7 / rails 2.3.8

I have some HTML text stored in a model and I'd like to be be able to get the element containing the desired text's innerHTML.

I've looked at hpricot briefly, and didn't see any sort of .parent functionality after a text search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the Hpricot XPath selectors to find the parent element:

```
elem.search("..")
```

See https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/wiki/Supported-XPath-Expressions for more.